# Twitter-like input fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter, input, focus

[image: Twitter registration]

I'm trying to make some input fields that I would like to work like Twitter's registration form.

1. On focus the value text becomes light grey.
2. When you start typing the light grey default value disappears completely and the user-written text becomes #000000.
3. If you don't write anything and go out of focus the default text appears again.

How to achieve with jQuery?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I haven't really got anywhere except for the auto-removal value on focus. 

    $("input#cont_cont\\/email").focus(function () {
        var defVal = $(this)[0].defaultValue;
        if($(this).val() == defVal) { $(this).val(''); }
    });
    $("input#cont_cont\\/email").blur(function () {
        var defVal = $(this)[0].defaultValue;
        if($(this).val() == '') { $(this).val(defVal); }
    });

Comment: If you want Twitter-like, you're better off ditching most of jQuery UI and downloading Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this sample.

[How to specify some watermark text for a text input element ?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-specify-some-watermark-text-for-a-text-input-element/)

Comment: Sweet. Is there a live demo other than just the picture?

Comment: next to the pic, there is the html,script&css you can use that

Answer (score 4):

This is a sample way of doing this, making the value of the input set to what you want it to say, and have a label nearby (you can hide it, but have it in the dom) so you can grab its value and add/remove it.

```
// clear input on focus
    $('input.myclass').focus(function() {
        var inputlabel = $(this).attr('label');
        if($(this).val() == inputlabel) { $(this).val('').removeClass('inactive'); }
    });
    // restore text on blur if blank
    $('input.myclass').blur(function() {
        var inputlabel = $(this).attr('label');
        if($(this).val() == '') { $(this).val(inputlabel).addClass('inactive'); }
    });
```

You can also use the HTML5 `placeholder` on the input, ex `<input placeholder='Your name' type='text' />`, and it will clear the text on focus by default, but it won't work as you expect on all browsers.

Comment: Do you mean label tag or attribute? your text and code don't fit

Comment: Also note the `placeholder` attribute can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to work in older browsers. It won't behave exactly as the OP describes, but it's pretty close.